# 複数テーブルから一番上の行だけ取り出し、かつ特定列は合計値にしたい

Tags: sql, database

次の二つのテーブルがあります。

```
TABLE1
　myid
　name

TABLE2
　id
  myid
　count
```

TABLE1レコードが1つ、それに関連するTABLE2が3つ格納されているとします。

```
TABLE1
　myid = 1
  name = 太郎

TABLE2
　id = 1
  myid = 1
　count = 2

　id = 2
  myid = 1
　count = 3

　id = 3
  myid = 1
　count = 1
```

ここで、TABLE1とそれに関連するTABLE2レコードを全て取り出し、かつその一番上の行だけを結果として取得したいです。ただし、countの結果だけは三つのレコードの合計値を出したいです。

どのようなSQL文を書けばいいでしょうか？

望む取得結果は次のモノになります。

```
myid name id count
1    太郎　1  6
```

Answer (score 1):

select TABLE1.*, TABLE2.id, (select sum(count) from TABLE2 where TABLE2 .myid=TABLE1.myid) from TABLE1 inner join TABLE2 using (myid) order by myid asc limit 1;

ですかね？
試してないです

Answer (score 0):

グループ化してそれぞれの集計関数を使うだけです。ただし、SQLにおいて「一番上の行」という概念はないので、`MIN`など別の条件付けが必要です。

```
SELECT TABLE1.myid, name, id, count
FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN (SELECT myid, MIN(id) AS id, SUM(count) AS count
                        FROM TABLE2 GROUP BY myid) AS t ON TABLE1.myid = t.myid
```

とか。

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @id smallint
set @id = 1
select top 1
    t1.myid
    ,t1.name
    ,t2.myid
    ,(select sum(t2.count) from table2 t2 where t2.myid = @id)
     as 'count_sum' 
from table1 t1
where t1.myid = @id
group by 
    t1.myid
    ,t1.name
order by 
    t1.myid
```

こんな感じでどうでしょう？
ゴリ押しなので、あまりいい例ではありませんが・・・